# Android Practices for module creation

Tags: android, sails.js, crash-reports

I'm looking on working on an Crash Analytics manager for android and iOS. I'm using Sails.js/Node.js as my web backend and I'm almost done with the implementation. Looking to start creating the Android module. I'm kind of stuck on what I should take note of. Any help would be appreciated. I'm just doing these for fun. I know there are lot of Crash Analytics monitor. I use Fabric Crashlytics, Google Analytics, and ACRA. Just want to do mine out of fun. What I'm really concerned about is knowing and understanding Android Best Practices when creating modules for monitoring crash in Android. Thanks